# Substrate `translate` function

Tags: migration

I am trying to understand the usage of the `translate` function that is frequently used when writing migrations.

Is this function only being used to do changes to some existing storage values(I don't think so since why would it be different than the `map` function)?
For example, iterating through a `StorageMap` of `u32`s and increasing the values by 1.
Or is it also possible to use this function to adapt the data for the new type that is being stored for example in a `StorageMap`?
And if so how could something like that be achieved?

I haven't found any detailed documentation about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`translate`, as opposed to `mutate` or `map`, can be used to *translate* values between types.
It is sometimes used in storage migration exactly for that possibility.

Imagine a scenario like this:

- There is a pallet which stores `OldInfo` in a `StorageMap` called `MyMap`
- Now a migration should *translate* all `OldInfo` into `NewInfo` in that map

```rust
MyMap::translate::<OldInfo, _>(|_key, old| -> Option<NewInfo> {
    Some(old.to_new_format())
})
```

Would archive this.

I personally never use `translate` since it has a flaw. From the docs:

> NOTE: If a value fail to decode because storage is corrupted then it is skipped.

This means that if you have a type error in your migration by providing a faulty old type, it will just do nothing and carry over these old values **silently**.
This is harder to mess up when using a `storage_alias`.

It is probably a good idea in any case to check that all values still decode in the post-migration hook:

```rust
assert_eq!(MyMap::iter_values().count(), number_of_decodable_elements);
```

Comment: What does this exactly mean `it will just do nothing and carry over these old values silently`? Assume this happens, then we have still the old storage structure in the storage item. What happens then, when I query the storage after the faulty migration?

Comment: What would you suggest instead of `translate`? Assume you have an old storage structure and want to migrate to a new one. I mean when you use `storage_iter` or `storage_key_iter` you also need to specify how to decode the values. You could also have a wrong storage structure specified as the decoding struct.

Comment: What is a storage alias and how to use it? EDIT: Look here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/migrate-keytype-of-storagemap-without-breakin-api/3267#3267

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a47f200eebeb88a5bde6f1ed2be9728b82536dde/frame/support/src/storage/generator/map.rs#L199-L200

After the upgrade and faulty migration a new get query to the storage will fail to decode the new storage structure, right? This means, that then you can't access your storage anymore with the wrong decoding and you have to revert the storage structure for your runtime?

Comment: Rather iterate manually than use `translate`. Like [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/442394ac0769bf3248e6a3c2f00e0539c5d4ef91/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs#L567). You can also use `iter_keys` vs `iter_values` to find undecodable values and remove them in the migration like [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/9fe83c5d747b2007bc642607b1756929ba36ce4a/frame/scheduler/src/migration.rs#L104). But be careful not to modify the map while iterating and instead always call `collect()` first. Please ask a new Q about the `storage_alias`.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi I have one storagemap which stores u32 value,now i need to migrate this to Vec<T::AccountId>. How do it in storage migration?